# {ggdist}: How to prevent stat_dots() from overlapping stat_halfeye() in `position = "dodge"`

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, ggdist

I am trying to visualise the distribution of response variable using [raincloud plots](https://wellcomeopenresearch.org/articles/4-63), where one of the two factors is drawn on the x-axis (`am` here) and the other (`vs` here) is differentiated by colour. I used `position = "dodge"`, `position = "dodgejust"` and `position = position_dodge(width = <number>)` to align the factor `vs`, but the 'rain' created by `ggdist::stat_dots()` overlaps the 'clouds' drawn by `ggdist::stat_halfeye()`. In the figure below, the green dots overlap green 'clouds'. How should I stop this problematic behaviour?

[image]

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |>
  mutate(
    am = am |>
      as.factor(),
    vs = vs |>
      as.factor()
  ) |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = am,
      y = mpg,
      colour = vs,
      fill = vs
    )
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    # position = "dodge",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
    point_interval = median_qi,
    width = 0.5,
    .width = c(0.66, 0.95),
    interval_size_range = c(1.25, 2.5),
    interval_colour = "black",
    point_colour = "black",
    fatten_point = 3
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_dots(
    position = "dodge",
    #position = "dodgejust",
    #position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
    binwidth = 1,
    side = "left",
    dotsize = 1
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(
    begin = 0.3,
    end = 0.6,
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
  )
```

Comment: Use `ggdist::stat_dots(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), ...)` to ensure your position adjustment in the dots layers is aligned with the position adjustment in the half-eye layer.

Comment: @teunbrand Thank you for your comment. That is quite close! However, then, the dots overlaps the edges of the clouds (the bars). How should I add space between dots and clouds?

Comment: To nudge the x position a little bit after the dodging has been applied, you can use `aes(x = stage(am, after_scale = x - 0.05))` in the dots layer. Where `0.05` can be whatever number you find appropriate.

Comment: @teunbrand Thank you for your great solution! It magnificently works! Would you want to post your solution as an answer? I will definitely up-vote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three parameters you can adjust here that are relevant: `position`, `width` (equivalently `height` when horizontal), and `scale`. `width`/`height` and `scale` are illustrated in this diagram from the [slabinterval vignette](https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/articles/slabinterval.html):

[image: diagram of slabinterval properties]

In your case, `position` and `width` can be used to adjust how the geometries are dodged and how far apart they are dodged, but I don't recommend using them to prevent overlaps. As a general rule, if you want to use two ggdist geoms together and have them dodge correctly, they should have *the exact same* values of `position` and `width`.

(as an aside, I just realized you are also setting `binwidth` manually, which is likely to make this process painful. If you use the parameters below appropriately --- particularly `scale`, as I will show --- it will automatically pick a `binwidth` to fit your dotplot into the available space. So I will omit the `binwidth` parameter in what follows).

If you start with this plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdist)

df = mtcars |>
  mutate(
    am = am |>
      as.factor(),
    vs = vs |>
      as.factor()
  )

df |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = am,
      y = mpg,
      colour = vs,
      fill = vs
    )
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    position = "dodge",
    point_interval = median_qi,
    .width = c(0.66, 0.95),
    interval_size_range = c(1.25, 2.5),
    interval_colour = "black",
    point_colour = "black",
    fatten_point = 3
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_dots(
    position = "dodge",
    side = "left",
    dotsize = 1
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(
    begin = 0.3,
    end = 0.6,
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
  )
```

[image: raincloud plots with overlaps]

You can see the overlaps of dots and slabs. You could adjust `width` so that the two related subgroups within `vs` are closer together, but this does not guarantee no overlaps between dots and slabs, even though by chance there aren't any in this example (e.g. if the group where vs == 0 and am == 0 had some more values around 19, that density would overlap with the dots from the vs == 1 and am == 0 group):

```r
df |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = am,
      y = mpg,
      colour = vs,
      fill = vs
    )
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    # make sure position and width are the same for both geoms
    position = "dodge",
    width = 0.5,
    
    point_interval = median_qi,
    .width = c(0.66, 0.95),
    interval_size_range = c(1.25, 2.5),
    interval_colour = "black",
    point_colour = "black",
    fatten_point = 3
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_dots(
    # position and width same as the halfeye to keep them in sync
    position = "dodge",
    width = 0.5,
    
    side = "left",
    dotsize = 1
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(
    begin = 0.3,
    end = 0.6,
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
  )
```

[image: rainclouds closer together]

If you want to guarantee that the slabs and dots don't overlap, instead adjust the `scale` parameter. `scale` does not change the basic position of the geometries, instead it determines how much of the region allocated to the geometry is used to draw the slab (for geom_halfeye) or the dots (for geom_dots). When `scale == 1`, two adjacent slabs will just touch at their max point. Thus, if you have two geometries (like halfeye and dots) sharing the same space, you can set `scale` to a value less than `0.5` to guarantee they will not touch:

```r
df |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = am,
      y = mpg,
      colour = vs,
      fill = vs
    )
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    position = "dodge",
    scale = 0.5,
    point_interval = median_qi,
    .width = c(0.66, 0.95),
    interval_size_range = c(1.25, 2.5),
    interval_colour = "black",
    point_colour = "black",
    fatten_point = 3
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_dots(
    position = "dodge",
    scale = 0.5,
    side = "left",
    dotsize = 1
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(
    begin = 0.3,
    end = 0.6,
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
  )
```

[image: more rainclouds without overlaps]

Note that while `width` should be the same across the two geometries, `scale` does not have to be. Often depending on data you can even prevent overlaps with a value greater than 0.5.

You can see further discussion and an example of rainclouds in the [dotsinterval vignette](https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/articles/dotsinterval.html#rain-cloud-plots).

Finally, if you want the dots not to overlap the interval, you could either take @teunbrand's suggestion of using `after_scale` or supply a `justification` value greater than 1 to the dots geometry (`justification` controls the position of the dots relative to the interval):

```r
df |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = am,
      y = mpg,
      colour = vs,
      fill = vs
    )
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    position = "dodge",
    scale = 0.5,
    point_interval = median_qi,
    .width = c(0.66, 0.95),
    interval_size_range = c(1.25, 2.5),
    interval_colour = "black",
    point_colour = "black",
    fatten_point = 3
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_dots(
    position = "dodge",
    scale = 0.5,
    side = "left",
    dotsize = 1,
    justification = 1.2
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(
    begin = 0.3,
    end = 0.6,
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
  )
```

[image: rainclouds with dots not overlapping the interval]

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive guide by the very author of the package! Now I understand the machinery of `{ggdist}` better than before!